# $\int_{\partial B(0,2)} (2z-1)e^{\frac{z}{z-1}}dz$ without residue method

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Is there any other method to calculate the following integral apart from residue method?

$$\int_{\partial B(0,2)} (2z-1)e^{\frac{z}{z-1}}dz$$

The result (using residue method) is $4 \pi i e$, but I need to know if residue method is the only possible one to have this.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: write the integrand as $(2z-1)$(series of powers of $z/(z-1))$. Exchange integral an sum. Apply Cauchy to each summand.

Comment: Why we can exchange integral and the sum? Series arent convergent in 1

Comment: @lksz43, $\partial B(0,2)$ is far of 1.

Comment: oh right, its only boundary. thanks!